Error performing zusand store action from shadcn table column
I'm trying to add or remove data from Zusand store based on row selection in the shadcn (tanstack) table.
import { useStore } from '@/lib/store'

const onStatusChange = async (value: string | boolean, row: any) => {
  const { items, removeItem, updateQuantity, clearCart } = useStore();
  const addItem = useStore((state: any) => state.addItem);

  if (value) {
    removeItem(row?.original?.id);
  } else {
    addItem(row.original);
  }
}

export const Columns: ColumnDef<Module>[] = [
  {
    id: "select",
    header: ({ table }) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected()}
        onCheckedChange={(value) => table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(!!value)}
        aria-label="Select all"
      />
    ),
    cell: ({ row }) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={row.getIsSelected()}
        onCheckedChange={(value) => {
          onStatusChange(value, row.original);
          row.toggleSelected(!!value)
        }}
        aria-label="Select row"
      />
    ),
    enableSorting: false,
    enableHiding: false,
  },
}

I am getting following error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

at following line
 const { items, removeItem, updateQuantity, clearCart } = useCartStore();

Need help in understanding what this error means and how to resolve it.

The error line doesn't seem to be in the shown code?
